# PHP - Insert elemens into an array

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm working on a formular, but for the moment I just want to insert into an array my elements (I have books and authors).

I can display my books with author (name + surname) with the foreach, but I can't add more elements.

Here is the code with the form.

```
<H1>Exercice 2</H1>
<form method="POST">
    <label for"code" >Number :</label>
    <input id="code" name="code" type="number" />

    <label for"title">Title :</label>
    <input id="title" name="title" type="text" />

    <label for"author" >Author :</label>
    <input id="author" name="author" type="text" />
<button type="input" type="submit">Ok</button>
```

```
$title =  $_POST['title']; 
$code = $_POST['code'];
$author = $_POST['author'];

$book = array();
$book['code'] = 123;
$book['title'] = "Legendes";
$book['author'] = array("David", "Gemmel");

foreach($book as $value){
    $book['key'] = $value;
    var_dump($book);
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach($value as $otherValue) {
            echo($otherValue);
        }
    } else {
        echo($value);
    }
}
```

I did some searcch, but I don't think it works, it's using the array_push() method with the POST, but I don't know where I can manipulate my form into the array.

If you want some details, I'll be happy to do that =) I'm working on it, if i have some news, you will know =)

Have a nice day =)

Comment: Your `<input>` elements have no `name` attribute, and therefore aren't sent to the server. You mistakenly put them on the `<label>`. Also, you could just do `<label>Number : <input type="number" name="code" ></label>` to greatly simplify your HTML.

Comment: You have your assignment syntax backwards. It should be `$title = $_POST['title'];`.

Comment: If you want to add more values, you need to use a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: array_push? What array_push?

Comment: Update ! Thank you for your help, I'm a little ashamed by those mistakes (need coffee) XD Now I just need to add those datas. I will do search about 2-dimensional array, for the moment it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1) Assignments are in reverse. Correct way:

```
$myVar = $myValue
```

2) You need to set the **name** attribute in your inputs in order to be sent:

```
<input id="code" type="number" name="code" />
```

Then you can access them like:

```
$_POST['code']
```

3) To add an element by key in an array, use:

```
$array['key'] = $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Exercise 2 have some mistakes :

First, your HTML inputs must have the name attribute to be retrieved by post:

```
<h1>Exercice 2</h1>
<form method="post">
    <label>
       <input name="code" type="number" />
    </label>

    <button type="submit">Ok</button>
</form>
```

With PHP, you can access to any input value using the name:

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
```

Now, I think you want to "add" several books using this HTML form without a storage system. The problem is you can not do this if for every a new request since all the elements you have in your array will be deleted each time you run a new post request. To keep this information you need to use some persistent storage system as a database or others.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to want to keep the information for each book together, you need to use a multidimensional array - hence, you'll need to redo the whole thing. Here's a suggestion:

Form:

```
<h2>Exercice 2</h2>

<form method="post">
<label for"code">Number :</label>
<input id="code" name="code" type="number">

<label for"title">Title :</label>
<input id="title" name="title" type="text">

<label for"author-firstname">Author First Name:</label>
<input id="author-firstname" name="author-firstname" type="text">
<label for "author-lastname">Author Last Name:</label>
<input id="author-lastname" name="author-lastname" type="text">

<input type="submit" name="submit_book" value="Ok">
</form>
```

Fixed the name-problems, changed the heading (you never, ever use H1 for a form, H1 is strictly used for the site-wide heading/logo/name of site). Also changed the button into a simple `input type="submit"`.

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
$author = $_POST['author'];

$book = []; // changed this to modern PHP version array assignment
$book[0]['code'] = 123;
$book[0]['title'] = "Legendes";
$book[0]['author-firstname'] = "David";
$book[0]['author-lastname'] = "Gemmel"; // no reason to assign a separate array for first and last name, just use two array-keys

for ($c = 0; $c <= count($book); $c++) { //changed this to a for, counting the amount of entries in the $book array
    echo 'Title: '.$book[$c]['title'];
    echo 'Author: '.$book[$c]['author-firstname'].' '.$book[$c]['author-lastname'];
} // the content should probably be wrapped in a container of some sort, probably a <li> (and then a <ul>-list declared before the for-loop)
```

Now. None of this has anything to do with putting stuff INTO the array. That would be something like this (there isn't even a point of assigning the $_POST-variables for the code you posted. But, you can do something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_book'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    $author-firstname = $_POST['author-firstname'];
    $author-lastname = $_POST['author-lastname'];

    // however, if all you're doing is putting this into the array, no need to assigne the $_POST to variables, you can just do this:

    $temp_array = ['code'=>$_POST['code'],'title'=>$_POST['title'],'author-firstname'=>$_POST['author-firstname'],'author-lastname'=>$_POST['author-lastname']];
    $book[] = $temp_array;
}
```

So, that would replace the assigned variables at the beginning of your code.